# How to make a simple mini map for a Java rpg game

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paintcomponent

I have an array that holds the names and then displays the appropriate graphics using:

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

```
for(int i = 0; i<20; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<20; j++)
    {   
        if(testMap.getData(i+(rowX-7), j+(columnY-7)).indexOf("rock") >= 0)
        {
            g.drawImage(image3, j*50 + 5*add, i*50 + 5*add2, 50, 50, this); 
        }   
    }
}
```

This works well displaying the actual graphics of my game. However, for my minimap, I do the same thing, with different values and increased numbers in the 'i' and 'j' in the for loop. This creates a smaller version of the map with a bigger scope, which leaves me with this. (Note, I only included one of the drawImage() methods, I removed the rest here to make the code more readable):

[image: my rpg game]

This is pretty much my desired effect (aside from the positioning, which I can change easily), however, this only shows a smaller version of what I already see on the screen. Any larger than about 20 x20, though, and the game begins to lag heavily -- probably something to do with the terrible way that I coded it.

I have tried replacing the images with squares using fillRect, but it does not help the issue.

Here is the code of my main class if anybody would like to take a look: http://pastebin.com/eEQWs2DS

The for loop within the paintComponent method begins at around line 3160, the loop for the main display is around 2678. I set up the Jframe at around 1260.

So, with all that said, basically my question is this:

Is there a better, more efficient way to create my minimap? My idea was to generate an image at the beginning of the program so that the game wouldn't have to recalculate every time the frame refreshes. I could create the map in advance, but I would have to manually update that every time I changed the map, which is definitely a hassle. I am having trouble researching how to do the former. My other idea is to slow the refresh rate of the minimap only, but I also do not know how to do that.

Other than that, if there are any simple fixes to the lag issue, please enlighten me. I apologize for the very, very messy code -- This is my first time programming anything with a display so I sort of just...hacked at it until it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how easy this would be with your implementation, but instead of drawing an image, perhaps you could draw a square of a certain color based on what type of tile it should be?

For instance if you're looping through your list of tiles and you find a grass tile, you would first draw the grass tile at its proper location, then draw a smaller green square on the minimap.

The downside to this is that first you'd have to define what colors to use for the tiles, or perhaps when you load the tiles you can compute an average color for each one, and then just use that. Another issue is that the houses may not translate well on to the minimap, since the tiles have much more detail. You could draw some kind of house icon on the minimap instead of actually drawing any of the house tiles, though.

Basically, you want to use simpler representations of the objects in your map on the minimap, since it's smaller and less detail can be drawn anyway.

Comment: That was my first idea that I had. I have tried changing the colors using fillRect, but the same lag still occurred. I think the problem is that I am attempting to print 2500 images at 5 square pixels each twenty times a second.

Comment: Maybe try to simplify the amount of data in the map somehow. For instance instead of having it 50x50 squares, have it 15x15, or something similar, but make the squares represent a larger area. For example if you have a road that's 3 squares wide on the regular map, it would take up more room on the minimap than it should, but it would be a good enough representation of a road on a map. Similarly houses may only take up 1 tile, or larger ones a 2x2 area perhaps on the minimap and may not be to scale, but would fairly accurately represent where the houses actually are.

Comment: Perhaps instead of i++ and j++ on the for loop, I use i = i + 4, etc?
Thank you, I will try that.

Comment: That could work, although I think the houses might look a bit weird.

Comment: The mini map works quite nicely now, though it does fail to display anything that lies on an odd number away from the player (I set the intervals to 2). Other than that and more complex sprites, like as you said, the house, it works and allows me to happily move on.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how I do it in Tyrant (a Java roguelike):

- https://github.com/mikera/tyrant/blob/master/src/main/java/mikera/tyrant/LevelMapPanel.java

Key tricks:

- Use an offscreen `BufferedImage`. Cache this to avoid recreating it each time you paint.
- Use an `int[]` array to setup up a single colour for each tile
- Use setRGB with the array to draw all the map at once
- Draw the mini-map at x2 zoom to get 2x2 pixel blocks for each tile.

If you want to be even more efficient, keep a `changed` flag and only update the mini-map BufferedImage when something visible on the mini-map changes. I didn't think it was worth it as the above is already very efficient, but YMMV.